# dynamic sitemap returns (500) Internal Server Error, but loaded in the browser

Tags: php, cakephp, sitemap

I developed a dynamic sitemap for a webpage, listing all the items in the DB (42000).

This is the view code:

```
<?php echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>'; ?>

<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">
    <?php  foreach($urls as $url){ ?>
        <url>
            <loc><?php echo  $url; ?></loc>
            <priority>0.5</priority>
        </url>
    <?php  } ?>
</urlset>
```

All looked good while testing with a browser (except the slow load time of about 15s).
But when I when tested with several Sitemap validation tools:
http://www.xml-sitemaps.com/validate-xml-sitemap.html

It says my page returns 500 (Internal Server Error);
In fact in the browser were such header (debug, net tab), but the page loaded any way ?!

With further testing, there was nothing wrong with the data (db and php loaded for 1s)
and all was OK around 40,000 items which is 5mb page size, and 100,000 rows of html.

Haven't found any info about such limitations ...
I have similar site map on other sites with no such issues.
It may be something on the server, or something specific for the framework (CakePHP).

Problem is currently solved by lowering the limit and splitting the map in 2 files, but I m looking for more information what is the issue.

Comment: probably it is taking too long to load the page and it crashed. Can you view the sitemap directly on your server ?

Comment: @XuDing the time is around 15 sec for loading, but the server sends header 500 in the first second, when the above threshold are passed.

Comment: Can you view the site map page on your browser directly?

Comment: yes It loads normally in the browser, but you can see the 500 header in the debug console.

Comment: can you post the error log? it should be in app/tmp/logs/